# d3js svg viewBox will not allows calculations of window.innerWidth - 170

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I know my error is in re-sizing `.attr("width", x)` or not calculating width in `.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + x + " " + y )`.

- **How do I fix my code or is there other working solutions?**

**Working Code:**(initial pageload)

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth - 170 || e.clientWidth - 170 || g.clientWidth - 170;
    y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", y)
    .attr("class", "bubble")
```

Results are **window.innerWidth -170**

---

When changed to viewBox calculation is unresponsive.

**Non-responsive Code:**

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth - 170 || e.clientWidth - 170 || g.clientWidth - 170;
    y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + x + " " + y )
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .attr("class", "bubble")
```

Results are **window.innerWidth**

### How can I get viewBox to allow calculations/subtraction of 170px?

**Is there a working alternative to resizing svg?** I have attempted other methods without success; left that code at the bottom.

---

### **ANSWER**

---

It was `<div id="dots"></div>` to a simple:

```
<svg id="dots" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg>
```

I may have to update the link but it now makes the veiwBox do as expected. I have not changed any code I was not confused as to how it was suppose to work. The properties needed to control svg apparently were not fully built into D3.js unlike what I was led to believe.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing what setting `width`/`height` and setting the `viewBox` property mean on an `svg` element.

The `height` and `width` control the dimension of the `svg` element inside the `layout` of the DOM while the [`viewBox` sets the coordinate system](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) inside the `svg` element.

[image: SVG dimensions and viewBox]

Here, the size of the SVG element is `(300px, 500px)` but the coordinate system internally starts from `(-100, -100)` and has a `width` and `height` of `200` and `200` each.

As for making the graph responsive, take a look at [how `nvd3` handles window resizes](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/utils.js#L32) and how to maintain the coordinate system inside the SVG element upon resize using [`viewBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) and [`preserveAspectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute).

Comment: I totally get your image and how that should work I am not doing an inline code so I do not know if it works the same.?? Additionally, the first link you provided me about **["viewBox"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)** said  **"The value of the ‘viewBox’ attribute is a list of four numbers <min-x>, <min-y>, <width> and <height>, separated by whitespace"** This is exactaly what I have in the non-responsive code: = **.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + x + " " + y )**

Comment: What do you mean that by _inline code_? And your value of `viewBox` is correct, but it is not the same as setting the width/height of SVG. Creating a `jsFiddle` will help.

Comment: Understood but I am defining two point the starting Left,top corner(distance from WINDOW(0x,0y)) and then the right,bottom corner(distance from SVG starting(0x,0y)). Is the example above a percentage or am I missing the point? I wanting to understand not just get the answer which is awesome either way thanks for contributing

Comment: No, saying that `viewBox = '-123 -456 789 987'` means that where the SVG box's `(min-x, min-y)` point is will be set to coordinates `(-123, -456)` _inside_ the SVG box. This coordinate system has absolutely nothing to do with the `window(0, 0)`. I am afraid I'll not be able to help much more without an example of working code.

Comment: Correct, sorry meant veiwpornt() I think.. At veiwport(0,0) svg coordinate (123,456) anything below those two number are above or the the left of screen are non-seen. visible (width, height) of item will be (666, 531) combining (123,456) + (666, 531) = (789, 987)

Comment: I will get the jsfiddle this evening. But I start my svg at (0,0) and I need `x = window.innerWidth -170px` the viewBox is not allowing this calculation It accepts `x = window.innerWidth` if I can fix that I will remove this entire question...

Answer (score 0):

In your

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W377W/)

**Change `<div id="dots"></div>` to a simple:**

```
<svg id="dots" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"></svg>
```

It works in notepad++ **when I find a better way to call site I will post.**